# What is the difference between Global Double Mouse Click Center and Global Mouse Click Center

Tags: java, blueprism

**Context:**

For a Business object, on the application modeller I have identified an element as Edit(Java) Data type: Text. Then on an action stage inside the business object process, assign the `Global Double Mouse Click Center` to this element.

When run I receive the message:

> Unable to match any windows with the query terms.

Assigning Global Mouse Click Center to the same element did work.

Any body know the difference between double and single click action over an element? Why this error could happend?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know the difference between double and single click on an element, but I resolve the issue of go foward with simulate double click.

I try sending a `Global Mouse Click Center` twice, but it behave to slow. Then I tweak the element mapping on the Application Modelling and change parameters as `descendant` and `ancestor count`. Still slow response.

Finally, I create a region with `fix coordinate` and send the mouse click event twice on this region and works.

Hope this can help to any one who get the same issue.
Regards.